# IDependencyResolver differences

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I implemented a class `myDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver{}`.

When I am using `System.Web.Http.Dependencies`, it gives an error saying I didn't implement `BeginScope()` and `Dispose()`.

But when I am using using `System.Web.Mvc`, it has no problem.

Are they two different interfaces?  I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the mouse over the type you'll see the full namespace ;-)

And yes, they are diferent types. Same name, diferent namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.idependencyresolver(v=vs.108).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dependencies.idependencyresolver(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Exactly, a lot of webapi and mvc classes and interfaces have the same issue.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between them? I barely grasp the concept of dependency resolver.

Comment: From what I understand, the `IDependencyResolver` originally only existed in `System.Web.Mvc` (before WebApi was invented), so they decided to move it to the `System.Web.Http` namespace because the concept shouldn't be limited to MVC, however to prevent it being a breaking change for those using MVC, they duplicated it instead, causing the grief you're experiencing.

Comment: @jingchyu They do more or less the same, with the main difference been that the one in System.Web.Mvc use generics and the one in System.Web.Http returns Object instead. However you must use one or another depending in which technology are you working on